# FInding fft gives keyerror :'Aligned ' pandas

Tags: pandas, time-series, fft, fftpack

I have a time series data

I am trying to find the fft .But it gives keyerror :Aligned when trying to get the value

my data looks like below

[image: The data looks like this]

this is the code:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.fftpack
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

temp_fft = sp.fftpack.fft(data3)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like your data is a pandas series. fft works with numpy arrays rather than series.
Easy resolution is to convert your series into a numpy array either via

```
data3.values
```

or

```
np.array(data3)
```

You can then pass that array into fft function. So the end result is:

```
temp_fft = sp.fftpack.fft(data3.values)
```

This should work for you now.